# issue in delete query

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

The following query is not working .Please tell me what is wrong here.Its giving Error report:SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended". I am trying to delete the data from two tables at a time.

```
delete t1,t2 from x t1 inner join y t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t1.id in 
(SELECT object_id FROM z WHERE name = 'YourName');
```

Comment: The error is from Oracle but tag says MySql ...

Comment: ya i have edited the tag

Answer (score 2):

Deleting data from two tables at a time in a single query??? Not possible.

Comment: i want to delete at once from 3 tables how to perform this? i m using oracle sql and mybatis i want to delete from x_table and y_table where id=select id from z_table where obj_id="1234" also at the same time i want to delete 
from user_table id = select id from z_table where obj_id="1234" and user_id != in (select user id from main_table)

in short i want to delete the rows from 3 tables x_table,y_table and user_table for the given

Comment: how to write the stored proedure for this. I have a seperate post for this please reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033101/procedure-to-perform-delete-operation

Comment: Please read any tutorial and learn how to write procs. It will help u in the long run. Anyways I have answered on your question (your separate post). Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just can't delete data from two tables at the same time. You'll have to use 2 queries. Using Transactions may help with the consistency of your model.

Comment: we cannot join and perform as above?

Comment: No you can't :) You'll have to use as much queries as tables but that's not an issue ! It's perfectly normal, don't be frightened of performance impact ! Just embed them in a transaction to be certain of the consistency of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If t1 and t2 are inner joined, then your option is to make the reference `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so you only have to delete the parent row to automatically delete all children.

rgds.